# match chars, numeric and special chars within a pattern

Tags: regex, special-characters

within a string i could have the following:

```
this is a string ::foo:bar:: ::baz:123abc:: ::bäz:üéü:: ::#$%%:4/4::
```

how can i get all parts with starts with `::` and ends with `::` and match what is in between.
within those colons there are key, value pairs i need to filter out of the string.

if there wouldn't be special chars i the regex would look like this:

```
r'::([a-z0-9]+):([a-z0-9]+)::'
```

i could list those special chars manually but i don't think thats the right way to do this.

thx

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're using, but what about `r'::[^:]+:[^:]+::'`?

Comment: Your character class looks a bit weird. Are you sure whitespace and comma are allowed as well? If you just want to match lower-case Latin letters and digits, try `[a-z0-9]+`.

Comment: @shi: no that was an error from my side. comma and whitespace are not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With not-colon:

```
 r'::([^:]+):([^:]+)::'
```

Answer (score 2):

First you should mention the regex flavor/tool you'd like to use, but generally:

```
r'::([^:]+)::
```

Should capture the special chars as well.

HTH

Comment: i don't think that mentioning in which language i use it whould make a difference in the regex syntax but Im developing in python.

Comment: Actually does. E.g. in `sed` you must escape `(` pairs (too, and several other chars).

Comment: Masking the `(` isn't necessary, if you invoke sed with `sed -r ...`